# Do you import all Story Mode characters?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I read that with the New Game+ you can import maps, cash, items, shop unlocks and characters from Story Mode, i am wondering if you import all of them or if you can import only a couple and make up the rest (ie. only import the Highlander and Ricky)

Answer (score -1):

I doubt you can. However what you can do is add new members in the explorers guild and have the rest sit and wait.